# Blazor Server App RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider does not check regularly if AuthState is valid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor Server first time and im using default AuthenticationStateProvider.

- Once user logins i call this method;

```
    public async Task<CustomResult> Login(AdminDto admin) {
    if (admin == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(admin));
    var authState = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (authState.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true) {
      await Logout();
    }
    var expire = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CookieExpireMinutes);
    var resp = AdminLoginSession.Create(admin, expire);
    var sessionId = GetUniqueSessionId();
    Sessions.TryAdd(sessionId, resp);
    var claimsPrincipal = CreatePrincipalFromLoginResponse(admin);
    await _cookieUtil.SetValue(AdminLoginKey, sessionId, expire);
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
    return DomainResult.Ok(nameof(Login));
  }
```

This method is called when login email and password is correct and data provided is valid
Checks for if there is already existing authentication and removes it
Creates a timespan for expiration time in my case this is 1 day
Creates a AdminLoginSession which contains AdminDto and ExpireTime
Then adds the values to Session which is statically defined

`private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AdminLoginSession> Sessions { get; set; } = new();`

Then adds the sessionId to cookie by calling JsRuntime
NotifiesStateChanged and returns a custom result type

- This is logout method;

```
  public async Task Logout() {
    var sessionId = await _cookieUtil.GetValue(AdminLoginKey);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId) ) {
      await _cookieUtil.RemoveValue(AdminLoginKey);
      Sessions.TryRemove(sessionId, out _);
    }
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous)));
  }
```

Checks if session exists and removes it by JsRuntime then notifies state changed

- Here is GetAuthState method;

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() {
    //var identity = _anonymous.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    try {
      var sessionId = await _cookieUtil.GetValue(AdminLoginKey);
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
      Sessions.TryGetValue(sessionId, out var adminSession);
      if (adminSession is null) {
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous)));
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
      }
      var isExpired = adminSession.ExpireTime < DateTime.Now;
      if (isExpired) {
        Sessions.TryRemove(sessionId, out _);
        var aState = new AuthenticationState(_anonymous);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(aState));
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
      }
      var admin = adminSession.Admin;
      var principal = CreatePrincipalFromLoginResponse(admin);
      var state = new AuthenticationState(principal);
      return await Task.FromResult(state);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
      //Log.Error(ex, "Error getting authentication state");
      return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
    }
  }
```

Checks if sessionId cookie exists if exists checks if the ConcurrentDictionary has the value then check for expiration date

Now above methods are not maybe relevant to the real problem but im just sharing just in case

This is my class;

```
public class AdminAuthenticationStateProvider : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval { get; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
//and the functions
}
```

The method that should be called regularly to check authentication state is this;
I want this to be called every 5 seconds as set above

```
  protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var user = authenticationState.User;
    var isAuthenticated = user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
    if (!isAuthenticated) return false;
    var sessionId = await _cookieUtil.GetValue(AdminLoginKey);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) return false;
    Sessions.TryGetValue(sessionId, out var adminSession);
    if (adminSession is null) {
      return false;
    }
    var isExpired = adminSession.ExpireTime < DateTime.Now;
    if (isExpired) {
      Sessions.TryRemove(sessionId, out _);
      var aState = new AuthenticationState(_anonymous);
      NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(aState));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, AdminAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider, AdminAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AdminAuthenticationStateProvider>();
///app

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Layout View
Since the web app will not allow anything if user is not authenticated im using the authorize view in layout page, if user is not logged in it shows login page without redirecting

```
<RadzenDialog />
<RadzenNotification />
<RadzenContextMenu />
<RadzenTooltip />

<RadzenLayout >
  <AuthorizeView >
    <ChildContent>
      <LayoutSideNavBar></LayoutSideNavBar>
      <RadzenBody>
        <div class="rz-p-4">
          @Body
        </div>
      </RadzenBody>

    </ChildContent>
    <Authorizing>
      <SubPageAuthorizing></SubPageAuthorizing>
    </Authorizing>
    <NotAuthorized>
      <SubPageLogin></SubPageLogin>
    </NotAuthorized>
  </AuthorizeView>

</RadzenLayout>
<LayoutFooter></LayoutFooter>
```

Some answers to expected questions;

1. Why using Cookie ?
   I have tried ProtectedSessionStorage which is not persisted on another tab
   Also i have tried SessionStorage by Blazored which also same thing but plain text which is worse
   I have used localStorage as well which kinda same as cookie without expiration date, i think so i go with Cookie
2. Why using ConcurrentBag ?
   Well i need to somehow link the sessionId to a user, i might just use JWT which i dont have to store anything on server side but since this website is an admin panel and very few (max 10) people is going to use it i dont have any issues on scalibilty

Also i have a background task that removes expired sessionIds from the dictionary with an interval

I'm expecting when user logins and opens another tab for lets say viewing some data and logouts on the other tab, the first tab authentication state is not changed and server does not check for AuthState valid for the given interval

If user refreshes the first tab it works as expected and shows login page

I found it to be a bit weird dealing with all this and don't know why this does not work as it says.

Note: im not native english speaker im sorry if i made any typos or mis spelled some words

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#troubleshoot-errors